# Pass statement in an if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I try to understand, in this code, why python print the letter `"w"`? (I work with python 2.7.8):

```
LetterNum = 1

for Letter in 'Howdy!':
    if Letter == 'w':
        pass
        print 'Encountered w, not processed.'
    print ('Letter', LetterNum, 'is', Letter)
    LetterNum+= 1
```

I get this result:

```
>>> 
('Letter', 1, 'is', 'H')
('Letter', 2, 'is', 'o')
Encountered w, not processed.
('Letter', 3, 'is', 'w')
('Letter', 4, 'is', 'd')
('Letter', 5, 'is', 'y')
('Letter', 6, 'is', '!')
```

While I thought I should get this result:

```
>>> 
('Letter', 1, 'is', 'H')
('Letter', 2, 'is', 'o')
Encountered w, not processed.
('Letter', 4, 'is', 'd')
('Letter', 5, 'is', 'y')
('Letter', 6, 'is', '!')
>>>
```

Comment: If you need to keep track of index / loop number in a for loop, you should use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). So you would use `for LetterNum, Letter in enumerate('Howdy!'):` Note though that this is zero-indexed by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use pass as though it were continue. Pass does nothing, while continue skips the current iteration. Here is code that does what you want with correct usage of continue:

```
LetterNum = 1

for Letter in 'Howdy!':
    if Letter == 'w':
        print 'Encountered w, not processed.'
        continue
    print ('Letter', LetterNum, 'is', Letter)
    LetterNum+= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you get the logical error in the code through @DanDoe's answer.
But if you just want the required output , an alternate solution would be to use *else* statement.

```
LetterNum = 1
for Letter in 'Howdy!':
    if Letter == 'w':
        print 'Encountered w, not processed.'
    else:
        print ('Letter', LetterNum, 'is', Letter)
        LetterNum+= 1
```

This would improve the efficiency of the code.